# How to use sed command to change java package declaration in batch way

Tags: java, regex, bash, shell, sed

Previously, my java package declarations all start with 'zn' like "package zn.tree". Now after I changed the java folder path to remove 'zn' folder, I also want to change all java declarations to remove the prefix 'zn.' in a batch way. For example, I want change "package zn.tree" to "package tree".

So I decided to use bash script to change all the java files. After I googled, I wrote a script to use 'sed' command to do this job. However, it doesn't work and reports error. I still don't get familiar with the regex in 'sed'. My code is shown below:

```
#! /bin/bash
# change package declaration in batch way
for path in $(find $1 -type f -name "*.java"); do
        sed -i "" 's/\<zn/.\>//g' $path
done
```

Hope someone could give me some clues. Thank you.

Comment: Change your sed command to `sed -i 's/\<zn\>\.//g' $path` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't want to change the java file name. Instead, I want to change the content of the java file, like the java package declaration in it.

Comment: Just a note for the way you run the sed: there is no good reason why you would like to iterate through the results of the find command via bash for loop. Moreover it's not a good idea to use double quotes in as a name parameter for a find command (since such string can be expanded by bash). In short, I would run it this way: `find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs sed -i 's/\<zn/.\>//g'`

Comment: If using sed isn't a requirement...what about just using an IDE like eclipse, netbeans, or intellij? They have refactoring features that would allow you to do this without writing a script.  While learning to write the script is a worth while investment this may be better solved long term with an IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could do it with a one liner like,

```
find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec sed -i 's/^package zn\./package /1' {} \;
```

That will execute the `sed` command and instruct it to edit in-place on every matching file. Note that I assume you want to match the first line starting with "package zn." and replace it with "package " once.

Comment: thanks for your help. In your command, I saw the {} and \ in the end of command. I am not sure what do they mean? Can you give me some clues? @Elliott Frisch

Comment: Yes. They are part of `find -exec` and are replaced by the matching files. Try `find . -type f -name '*.java' -exec echo {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Using the refactoring feature of an IDE such as Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans will save you a lot of time for those needs. In IntelliJ, you would just create your new package and drag-and-drop your classes from the old package to the new one.